# rm no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

tengo un problema al momento de crear un nuevo proyecto en laravel con jetstream hago lo siguiente:

```
laravel new proyecto --jet
```

me aparece lo siguiente:

```
Which Jetstream stack do you prefer? [0] livewire [1] inertia
```

Selecciono la opción número **0** para trabajar con livewire, luego me aparece esto:

```
Will your application use teams? (yes/no) [no]:
```

No quiero usar equipos por lo que escribo la opción **no**, pero después de darle enter me aparece este mensaje:

**"rm" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,                                                              programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.**

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?
gracias !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un error reportado ya hace tiempo y que como puedes [ver ya está solucionado](https://github.com/laravel/installer/pull/133)

Entonces la manera más simple es instalar la versión más reciente de dicho instalador así:

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

Aquí en [el repositorio](https://github.com/laravel/installer) puedesver cual es la versión más reciente

Comment: Excelente, habia olvidado eso, muchas gracias !!